# Result Wont Save to Variable After AJAX call - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a radio button, which then determines which one is selected.

I make a call to my home controller and in my home controller I have an if statement. The if statement then points to my model which returns a number from the database.

When I echo out / console log it in the AJAX the number appears. Although I need to extract that number and place it as a shipping fee in my code.

When I do something like return $shipping nothing gets returned

In another section I need to call it like: $shipping = $this->shipping_zones();

Is there a reason why its not saving?

**AJAX**

```
function Shipping_SelfFull(selforfull) {

  var self_full = selforfull.value;
  var url = "";

  if (self_full == 'self') {
    url = base_url+'index.php/home/shipping_zones/self';
    console.log('you chose self');
    update_calc_cart();

  } else if (self_full == 'full') {
    url = base_url+'index.php/home/shipping_zones/full';
    console.log('you chose full');
    update_calc_cart();

  }

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(html){
      var shipping = html;
      console.log(html);
    }
  });
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
function shipping_zones($para1=""){
  $shipping = '';

  if ($para1 == 'self') {
    $shipping = $this->crud_model->shipping_based_on_zones('self');
    echo $shipping;
    return $shipping;
  }

  if ($para1 == 'full') {
    $shipping = $this->crud_model->shipping_based_on_zones('full');
    echo $shipping;
    return $shipping;
  }
  return $shipping;
}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
// Shipping Based On Zones
function shipping_based_on_zones($para1=""){

  if ($this->session->userdata('user_login') == "yes") {
    $current_user_id = $this->session->user_id;
    $user_membership_level = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$current_user_id'")->row()->membership_level;
    $user_country = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$current_user_id'")->row()->country;
    $country_zone_result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country_zones WHERE country LIKE '%\"$user_country\"%'");
  }

  if ($user_membership_level == '1') {
    if ($para1 == 'self') {
      return $country_zone_result->row()->vip_self_shipping;
    } elseif ($para1 == 'full') {
      return $country_zone_result->row()->vip_full_shipping;
    }
  }


  if (($user_membership_level >= '2') && ($user_membership_level <= '5')) {
    if ($para1 == 'self') {
      return $country_zone_result->row()->member_self_shipping;
    } elseif ($para1 == 'full') {
      return $country_zone_result->row()->member_full_shipping;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: is this all your code? there is no data being sent over the ajax call if so? use `'data: {}'

Comment: May be you need to echo json_encode your return data in controller like
return json_encode($shipping);

Comment: No I mean in the AJAX i will console log the result. The result will show. Although I need to save that result in home controller and then display it somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request has not been completed, remember ajax is asynchronous. One way to get around it is to force it to be synchronous. With that being said in your Ajax try using

> **async: false**

something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(html){
    alert(html);
    var shipping = html;
    console.log(html);
    }
 });
```

That works just fine for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tired doesn't work. The thing is from the home controller I need it to store the variable and then in another piece of code the cart stuff I need to call this function but nothing gets called back